Permutation of positive integers

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_1=1$ and for each $n \geq 1$ $a_{n+1}$ is the smallest positive integer distinct from $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ such that $\gcd(a_{n+1}a_n+1,a_i)=1$ for each $i=1,2,...,n$. How to prove that every positive integer appears in $a_n$?

This question was asked on a Brazilian constest. According to one of the contestants the official solution was flawed and the problem remains open. Is this result true?

"According to one of the contestants the official solution was flawed and the problem remains open." Very cool!

First few terms (not on OEIS): 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 7, 16, 12, 13, 24, 14, 15, 18, 11, 30, 19, 22, 21, 20, 23, 26, 17, 36, 28, 25, 42, 31, 46, 43, 40, 33, 34, 27, 44, 29, 32, 38, 39, 48, 35, 56, 41, 62, 45, 50, 47...

It will be added soon as https://oeis.org/A377362

Maybe one can define a "height" function $h$ defined by $h(\prod_{i}p_{i}^{a_{i}}):=\sum_{i}i.a_{i}$ and see if the terms of the sequence are arranged in increasing order of their heights.
